# If / else statements within a function

Tags: javascript, function

I've been going through the Eloquent Javascript book but I just started messing around with some of their examples. I've tried to make a function with multiple different states when you enter in a different value for the function.

```
const missileLaunch = function() {
    if (missileLaunch(SafeMode)) {
        console.log("The missiles are not ready to launch")
    } else if (missileLaunch(Loaded)) {
        console.log("The missiles have been targeted")
    } else if (missileLaunch(UraniumNotEnriched)) {
        console.log("The uranium has ot been enriched enough")
    }
};

missileLaunch(SafeMode);
```

It tells me the SafeMode state of the function is not defined.

```
missileLaunch(SafeMode);
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: I _think_ you're trying to do [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/pzfj3kh9/1/) but it's hard to tell. I think you need to keep reading.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing SafeMode, Loaded and UraniumNotEnriched function parameters while defining the function. You should use SafeMode, Loaded and UraniumNotEnriched as parameter as code snippet mentioned uses these parameters for conditional check.

Following should work:
`const missileLaunch = function(SafeMode, Loaded, UraniumNotEnriched )`

Answer (score 0):

Couple of problem with your code

```
const missileLaunch = function() {
    if (missileLaunch(SafeMode)) {
        console.log("The missiles are not ready to launch")
    } else if (missileLaunch(Loaded)) {
        console.log("The missiles have been targeted")
    } else if (missileLaunch(UraniumNotEnriched)) {
        console.log("The uranium has ot been enriched enough")
    }
};

missileLaunch(SafeMode);
```

First problem, you are invoking function `missileLaunch` with a parameter, but when you define `missileLaunch`, it's a function that has no parameter.

So to fix first problem, you can give it a parameter like below

```
const missileLaunch = function(parameter) {
  ...
};
```

Second possibility is you've defined a global variable `SafeMode`, but the value of the variable is `undefined`. So you may do a `console.log(SafeMode)` before you invoking `missileLaunch`, a step for debugging, as below:

```
console.log('SafeMode value is: ', SafeMode);
missileLaunch(SafeMode)
```